# How do I replace a glyphicon with an img_tag in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

Here is my code

`<%= render partial: 'negotiations/company_selection_placeholder', locals: {type: 'Removal', company: removal, icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home'} %>`

this is the image i want to put in instead of the icon

`<%= image_tag 'askingPrice.svg', class: "imgstage" %>`

Here's the company_selection_placeholder partial:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <%= type %>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the partial code in here?

Comment: <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><%= type %></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the comment you posted above is the entire partial, you need to do this:

```
<%= render partial: 'negotiations/company_selection_placeholder', locals: {type: 'Removal', company: removal} %>
```

and in your partial:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> 
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <%= image_tag 'askingPrice.svg', class: "imgstage" %> <!-- not sure if this is where you need your icon, but you should be able to use CSS to move it around from here -->
    <%= type %>
  </div> 
</div>
```